# plotting 3 categories on a matplotlib bar chart when one of them has no values for part of the x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I've been working with my own IMDB data to practice pandas and plotting, and have created a bar chart that is supposed to show the rating distribution between 3 types of ratings:
TV series, Movies, and TV episodes.

The issue is that I have no ratings of 1 or 2 for any TV Series in my dataset.
I would like to show 0% for 1 and 2 on the x axis for TV Series.

This is the code I've come up with so far:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
x_axis = np.arange(1,11)
movies_x = movies['your rating'].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()*100
tvseries_x = tvseries['your rating'].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()*100
tveps_x = tveps['your rating'].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()*100

width = 0.3
ax.bar(x_axis-width, movies_x, width, label = 'Movies')
ax.bar(x_axis, tveps_x, width, label = 'Episodes')
ax.bar(x_axis[2:]+width, tvseries_x, width, label = 'Series')
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], color='blue', fmt='%.f%%', fontsize=8)
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[1], color='red', fmt='%.f%%', fontsize=8)
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[2], color='green', fmt='%.f%%', fontsize=8)
ax.set_xticks(x_axis)
ax.set_xlabel('Rating')
ax.set_ylabel('Percent')
ax.set_title('Rating Distribution per rating type')
ax.legend(loc=6)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

My workaround was to start plotting TV Series from 3-10 (x_axis[2:]),
else I get "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (10,) and arg 1 with shape (8,)."

I've searched around here a lot, all I could find are questions where the distribution is based on the X axis (e.g. percentage per each rating group). Manually editing the series to add 1,2 seems like not an ideal solution.

Would appreciate any input /  tips.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the data? It will help to solve the question.

Comment: I would attach the CSV but it seems that goes against the site..
The main data set has the column  'your rating' for each episode, tv series and movie rated, ranging from 1 to 10. I split the original dataframe to these above 3 types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is not provided, I will answer the question by generating a (fake) dataset for movie ratings.

**Reproducing the error:**

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import random
import numpy as np

# The dataframe will have one column with movie ratings from 3 to 10.
movies = pd.DataFrame({"your rating" : random.choices(range(3, 11), k = 100)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
x_axis = np.arange(1, 11)

# Get percentage of ratings 
movies_x = movies['your rating'].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()*100

ax.bar(x_axis, movies_x, label = 'Movies')
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], color='blue', fmt='%.f%%', fontsize=8)
ax.set_xticks(x_axis)
ax.set_xlabel('Rating')
ax.set_ylabel('Percent')
ax.set_title('Rating Distribution per rating type')
ax.legend(loc=6)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This gives the error:

`ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (10,) and arg 1 with shape (8,).`

**Solving the error:**

You will have to make sure the Series' ending with `_x` (which store percentages of different ratings) have indices from 1 to 10. To do this without worrying which ratings do not exit in the dataset, we can try:

```
random.seed(100)

movies = pd.DataFrame({"your rating" : random.choices(range(3, 11), k = 100)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
x_axis = np.arange(1, 11)


# Get percentage of ratings 
movies_x = movies['your rating'].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()*100

# Code of interest
ratings = dict.fromkeys(set(range(1, 10)).difference(movies_x.index), 0)
movies_x = movies_x.combine(pd.Series(ratings), max, 0)
print(movies_x) 

ax.bar(x_axis, movies_x, label = 'Movies')
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], color='blue', fmt='%.f%%', fontsize=8)
ax.set_xticks(x_axis)
ax.set_xlabel('Rating')
ax.set_ylabel('Percent')
ax.set_title('Rating Distribution per rating type')
ax.legend(loc=6)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This gives `movies_x` as:

```
1      0.0
2      0.0
3      8.0
4     15.0
5      9.0
6     10.0
7     16.0
8     16.0
9     15.0
10    11.0
```

and the figure output as:

[image]